# How to fetch data from AWS redshift database using reactJS/Javascript?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a use case, in which I need to fetch data from the AWS Redshift database and display it in a react component.

Can anyone help with how to do it?

Note:- I installed aws-sdk package from npm. But, I am unsure of how to use that to fetch AWS Redshift data.

Answer (score 0):

Great question.

You cannot read redshift data directly from web. You need to go through intermediate service. Also I would not recommend to read data from redshift directly, it cannot scale very well and will be pricey if you want it scale for transactional queries.

**Here are few suggestions:**

1. If you are reading data for transaction purpose, use an RDS and you can use GraphQL with appsync.
2. If redshift is not primary requirement, would recommend to use DynamoDB along with appsync, which will be very good for front end speedier output.
3. Use Redshift only for analytical queries and unload the data to S3 and access it from there.

**EDIT 1:**

Appsync with dynamodb resolvers

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  This makes sense and clears the picture for me.

Comment: So my next question will be, can we use DynamoDB with a react app hosted with AWS amplify?

Comment: Yes. You can use it along with appsync which include authentication and authorization for your graphql query calls.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you share a bit of sample code or reference for achieving this? I mean the sample code for DynamoDB and app sync stuff.